# Forwarding incoming http requests are getting queued up

Tags: go

Appreciate a response from a senior level architect who has a deep understanding of concurrency and experience in go language

I've a custom apparatus to handle, process and respond to incoming client requests and server is simply wrapping all the incoming requests, the `request` and `responseWriter` in an object and delegating to the apparatus.

The problem I'm observing based on my unit tests (spawning 1000 http request to localhost) is that all the requests are processed in sequence instead concurrently, it's like they are in

Each request is taking more time than the previous one simply telling me it's a queue. If for example a database based request takes `200 ms`.

```
Request 1 -> taking 200 ms
Request 2 -> taking 400 ms
Request 3 -> taking 600 ms
```

Each request is waiting for the previous request to finish, I'm not doing something right when it comes to delegating incoming requests to the apparatus so I've prepared a trimmed down version that simply decodes the JWT token and responds to the client, please run test/token_test.go. [Download Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/merneoewwfzjrtx/apparatus.zip?dl=0)

**application.go**

```
func main() {
        a := delegate.Apparatus{}
        a.Run()
}
```

**apparatus.go**

```
type Apparatus struct {}

func (a *Apparatus) Run() { // initialize the server
        server := Server{}
        server.SetDelegate(a) // tell server to forward requests to itself
        server.StartServer() // start the server
}

func (a *Apparatus) Handle(request *Request) { // interface impl
        a.RenewToken(request) // delegate request to a time consuming func
}
```

**server.go**

```
type Server struct {}

func (s *Server) StartServer() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
        fmt.Println("Server Listening at 8080")
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
        if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
        }
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { // delegate to apparatus
        delegate.Handle(&Request{ResponseWriter: w, Request: r})
}

func (s *Server) SetDelegate(d IHandler) {
        delegate = d
}
```

**request.go** wrapper for the `request` and `responseWriter`

```
type Request struct {
        ResponseWriter http.ResponseWriter
        Request        *http.Request
}
```

**ihandler.go** interface for the apparatus

```
type IHandler interface {
        Handle(request *Request)
}
```

**test/token_test.go** this will show each successive request is taking more and more time than the previous one

```
func MakeRequest(ch chan<-int, index int) {
        t0 := time.Now()
        response, _ := http.Get("http://localhost:8080?authToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6Mjg4LCJuYmYiOjE0NDQ0Nzg0MDAsInJhbmQiOjAuOTI2OTg2ODAzNTc0NDE0Mn0.3HC8lEDGlui_sOtkeMn52Wnt9HUuH4lFbk7ubdUK_Z4&index=" + strconv.Itoa(index))
        t1 := time.Now()
        ch <- response.StatusCode
        fmt.Printf("The call took %v to run.\n", t1.Sub(t0))
}

func TestConcurrent(t *testing.T) {
        start := time.Now()
        ch := make(chan int)
        max := 1000

        for i:=0; i<max; i++ {
                    go MakeRequest(ch, i)
        }

        for i:=0; i<max; i++ {
                    if <-ch != 200 {t.Error("Expecting status code 200")}
        }
        fmt.Printf("%.2fs elapsed", time.Since(start).Seconds())
}
```

It's best to [download the project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/merneoewwfzjrtx/apparatus.zip?dl=0) and test. I suspect the problem is in the server.go (line 24). I'm not delegating the request in a right way and they are simply queuing up.

Solution I'm looking for is how can I delegate/forward the incoming requests concurrently.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce on my laptop (i5 5200u, ubuntu 16.04.2, go1.8).
line 24 looks fine, unless there are some blocking operstions in jwt. It's very unlikely. Maybe you faced this problem because of scheduler. Try to reduce the number of parallel running goroutines and tune GOMAXPROCS.

Comment: Once you run unit test you'd notice that each log statement, the time it's take to run is increasing compared to last one. What's the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: no it doesn't, there is some deviation: from 20ms to 200ms, but looks like it has some kind of uniform distribution.

Comment: In my actual project with database query, spawning 1000 http requests, each successive request increasing in time, leading to the the last one taking 19 sec to complete. If you see my code critically do you see any problem with the delegating part?

Comment: Line 22 server.go, the function handler getting called by go runtime when a request comes in, is it a go routine itself?

Comment: I don't see any major issues with the delegation part. Are you sure that the problem is not on the side of your DB?
Golang http server accepts incoming connections and spawns a new goroutine for each, as it's stated in documentation for http package.

Comment: And I still suggest you to limit a number of parallel running goroutines. You may process less request in parallel. But you can spend less time on processing all the requests.

Comment: It's quite possible that database is the bottleneck, your code review gave confidence though. I'm going to create another test without using apparatus to see if database is the culprit.

Comment: When you say limit number of parallel go routines, I didn't get that. My apparatus has no go routines and is completely synchronous, there's no need actually. My objective was to simulate how system behaves if 1000 users are making requests to the services. Is this methodology right or should I've done in a different way?

Comment: Your apparatus uses goroutines implicitly when it handles http requests. When I suggested you to limit the number of parallel running goroutines, I was talking about token_test.go. I believe there is nothing wrong with your methodology.

Comment: I ran a unit test directly on the database query function calling 1000 times, it's a remote database. 1st call took 600 ms and it increased gradually to 3.5 sec